# Develop web by Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making basic web page by Flutter 
so I am using Android Studio
but how can I check web screen by Chrome?
I have made web page by HTML but this is my first time making it with Flutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow this tutorial:

https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web

1. Run the following commands to use the latest version of the Flutter SDK from the beta channel and enable web support:

   ```
   flutter channel beta
   flutter upgrade
   flutter config --enable-web
   ```
2. Once web is enabled, the flutter devices command outputs a Chrome device that opens the Chrome browser with your app running, and a Web Server that provides the URL serving the app.

   ```
   flutter devices
   ```
3. Create and run

   ```
   flutter create myapp
   cd myapp
   flutter run -d chrome
   ```
4. Alternatively, to add web support to an existing project, then run it in Chrome, do the following:

   ```
   cd existing-project
   flutter create .
   flutter run -d chrome
   ```

Comment: I have solved the problem in the way you suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change your flutter channel to master and then when you click on the run button it will give you two options whether to run on chrome or the emulator